# Android Scroll Text View in Coordinatore layout + Recycler View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-coordinatorlayout

In my layout I have a Card View Layout containing HashTagView and then followed by recycler view. Using my existing code I am able to scroll through the recycler view. But I also want to be able to scroll the HashTagView  itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_id"
    tools:context="mymainactivity.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView style="@style/Card">

                <LinearLayout style="@style/CardContainer"
                    android:isScrollContainer="true">


                        <com.greenfrvr.hashtagview.HashtagView
                            android:id="@+id/hashtags6"
                            style="@style/HashtagView"
                            app:rowGravity="center"
                            app:rowMode="stretch"
                            app:selectionMode="true"
                            app:tagBackground="@drawable/item_bg_1"
                            app:tagForeground="@drawable/flat_button_light"
                            app:tagPaddingBottom="@dimen/padding_vertical"
                            app:tagPaddingLeft="@dimen/padding_horizontal"
                            app:tagPaddingRight="@dimen/padding_horizontal"
                            app:tagPaddingTop="@dimen/padding_vertical"
                            app:tagTextColor="#E5E5E5" />



                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to acheive this kind of layout:-

[image: Sample Layout of Samsung Galary App]